# how to extract a json data using flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

In my fluter app i have a list of json object. and with this object i use it to fetch other datas.the return type is `Map<int, List<int>>`, and the object structure is as follows.

```
{1:[1,7], 2:[1,141]}
{2:[142, 252]}
{2:[253, 286], 3:[1,92]}
...
```

this is what it returns. the first number indicates the chapter, the arrays are the verse start and end. so what i wanted todo with this is to get the chapter names, the verse start and end, separately.

so how can i map through this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer would be iterating through the `data`.

```
List<Map<int, List<int>>> data = [
  {1:[1,7], 2:[1,141]},
  {2:[142, 252]},
  {2:[253, 286], 3:[1,92]}
];

for (var item in data) {
  item.forEach((key, value) {
    print('Chapter $key verse $value');
  });
}
```

Output:

```
Chapter 1 verse [1, 7]
Chapter 2 verse [1, 141]
Chapter 2 verse [142, 252]
Chapter 2 verse [253, 286]
Chapter 3 verse [1, 92]
```

Comment: actually the data it's returning is of type ` Map<int, List<int>> ` and when i try to use it in for loop it throws `The type 'Map<int, List<int>>' used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable.` how can i overcome this